# Web pdf viewer plugin without download capability

Tags: html, flash, pdf

I am trying to embed few PDF files into my webpage and I don't want users to be able to download them.
Is there anything I can do to achieve this(flash or something else perhaps)?

To make myself more clear, I want something like pdf viewer on scribd. It allows you to read the files but does not allow you to download it. Ofcourse, users can copy-paste text but that's ok. I don't want them to download the complete file..

Answer (score 0):

If a commercial library works for you, you can try with [Amyuni PDF Creator.Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/) (Windows-only) and in particular the method [ExportToHTML5Ex](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Developer_Documentation.htm#Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_WinRT/Introduction_RT.htm).

Using this approach, you can convert each page of your PDF files into an html page based on HTML5 (or as an HTML code fragment inside `<div>` tags), you could then insert the result into another page of your website, and finally send the resulting page as response.

This way you can avoid sending the whole PDF document to the browser, (since you can send one page at a time), you will avoid degrading your PDF content as raster images, and you will still allow copy-pasting text. This approach will work for any [PDF files where text extraction is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12190234/501196).

Comment: Any Linux/PHP options?