# pdf strange characters on copying or with xpdf

Tags: php, linux, pdf, xpdf

on a linux server I'm using xpdf (whith php) to extract informations from pdf files

On some files all is OK

But on some others the text extracted is very strange !

When I see the pdf on acrobat reader I see normal text

But when extracted I get for example :

```
de? A8HC8 A
  QFPY 8 A H
        ?f                                   de? A8B=8AN Y?N
                                               QFPXgHBHGe BB
```

Also when I copy and past from the pdf to notepad or notepad++ on my computer windows 8.1 I see these strange characters

Any help please?
regards

Comment: No it's not I can copy but when I past the result is like I said before :(

Comment: See [PDF copy paste gives garbage text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184304/pdf-copy-paste-gives-garbage-text).